# rvest: xpath get text at current node with sub nodes removed

Tags: r, xpath, rvest

I have some text that is nested within a div tag that I want to grab.  In particular the address from the MWE below (`Hillsgrove, Missouri 13231-1123`).  Inside of this div tag are other tags I wish to ignore.  I'd like to grab just the text at the current div tag after the first `<br />`.  At the very least I'd like to get back the subtitle + the address without the other subnode text but ideally I'd like the text for address only.

I'm using the `rvest` package from R for this task but it seems this is a more general xpath question.

### MWE

```
library(xml2); library(rvest); library(dplyr)

minimal <- read_html(
"<!doctype html>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<title>blah</title>
<div class=\"span4\"> 
    <a href='http://www.stuff.com'>
        <strong>Sub Title</strong>
     </a>
  <br />
  Hillsgrove, Missouri 13231-1123<br />
  <span id=\"phone\">(5555) 555-5555</span><br />
  <a target=\"_blank\" href='http://www.morestuff.com'>www.morestuff.com</a>
  <br /><br />
</div>"
)

minimal %>%
    html_nodes(xpath = '//div[@class="span4"]') %>%
    html_text() 

## [1] " \n    \n        Sub Title\n     \n  \n  Hillsgrove, Missouri 13231-1123(5555) 555-5555www.morestuff.com\n  "
```

### Desired Outcome

```
## Hillsgrove, Missouri 13231-1123
```

### I'd Settle For

```
## " \n    \n        Sub Title\n     \n  \n  Hillsgrove, Missouri 13231-1123"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the text nodes for the current node, use `text()`

```
minimal %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = '//div[@class="span4"]/text()') %>%
  html_text() 
# [1] " \n  "                               "\n  "                               
# [3] "\n  Hillsgrove, Missouri 13231-1123" "\n  "
```

Can you can see that does return the newlines and white space, but that should be easy to strip out.

Comment: Brilliant...did not know aout that.